# Flutter PageView.builder with animated Children sizes

Tags: dart, flutter, pageviews

I'm trying to recreate this:
[image]
I've tried with a `PageView.builder`, and got this far (sorry for the ugliness of colors but it's for visualization purposes):

[image]

This is the Code:

```
Container(
    height: 40 * 2 + 100.0,
    child: PageView.builder(

      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: controller,
      itemCount: 9,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        double value = 1.0;

        try {
          value = controller.hasClients
              ? controller.page - index
              : 1.0;
        } catch (e) {
          value = 1.0;
        }
        value = value.abs().clamp(0.0, 1.0);
        value = 1 - value;

        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0),
          child: Container(
            width: value == 1.0 ? 80.0 : 60.0,
            height: 30.0,
            color: Color.lerp(Colors.green,
                Colors.red, value),
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  index.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(

                      color: Color.lerp(
                          Colors.red, Colors.black, value),
                      fontSize:  lerpDouble(20.0, 40.0, value)),
                )),
          ),
        );
      },

    ))
```

And the controller variable is this:

```
controller = new PageController(initialPage: 5, viewportFraction:  1/4);
controller.addListener(() {
  setState(() {});
```

As you can see I managed to change the color and textSize to the "selected" item (the red ones), but even If I try to set its size to be bigger, it has no effects. I tried with a ListView.builder which made me set different sizes but with it I didn't have page Snapping and a default initial Page, so I opted out.

hope everything is clear.

Is it possible to do it, and if it is, how Could I do it?

Answer (score -2):

I know its an old question but you can change width and height by changing margin of the container. You have to basically change a container (this one inside the Padding widget) margins values by value of your "value" variable and also I would highly suggest using AnimatedContainer for out of the box animations. Add this code to your container:

```
EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, right: value == 1.0? 20 : 40, left: value == 1.0? 20 : 40, top: value == 1.0? 150 : 250),
```

You should also remove this code from the container:

```
width: value == 1.0 ? 80.0 : 60.0,
height: 30.0,
```